# How can I access package-local fields of parent class in the same package but in different jar?

Tags: java, android, access-control

And I am trying to override `CursorLoader`'s `public Cursor loadInBackground()` method, so I tried in my app:

```
package android.content;

public class DistinctCursorLoader extends CursorLoader {
    @Override
    public Cursor loadInBackground() {
        // I need to use mUri, mProjection, mSelection, mSortOrder
```

But these "package-local" fields of CursorLoader are not visible to DistinctCursorLoader even-though they are in the same package (though obviously not in the same jar)

This is from CursorLoader.java (android's source):

```
package android.content;

public class CursorLoader extends AsyncTaskLoader<Cursor> {
    Uri mUri;
    String[] mProjection;
    String mSelection;
    String[] mSelectionArgs;
    String mSortOrder;
```

Comment: Are they being loaded by a different classloader?

Comment: I don't do anything in order to load them differently, but I don't know how it works in android. However worth to note, that even in AndroidStudio it already complains about those fields, it's not a run-time problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't simply make changes to the Android platform by sticking yourself into its namespace.  The source code you see for Android platform components in the IDE is provided as a convenience for you to learn about the platform, not access its non-public APIs.

All the classes in android.* live on the device itself at runtime.  They are not bundled into the app.  So, first of all, you don't have a guarantee that those specific fields are going to exist since things may change between versions of Android.  Second, the fields may have been renamed or obfuscated before shipping to the device because they are not public API and do not have expectation to be directly accessed by app code.

If you are feeling very rebellious, you can try to use reflection at runtime to find and make changes to hidden APIs, but that will surely cause you problems in the future.  So don't do that.

Comment: So how does this "package-local" access permission work in java? According to documents I saw it should let other classes in the "same" package see them. It looks like they don't see it. My guess is it's because they're in a different jar.

Comment: It's not a matter of which jar.  It's a matter of being entirely unavailable at the time of compilation because the *only* time the symbols matter is at runtime on the device.  Given that there's no fewer than 10,000 devices out there running some form of Android, how can you be certain that a non-public/protected field you're looking for even exists with the name and type you expect?  You can't.  And you shouldn't.